# Adding single item to enumerable

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a more elegant solution for adding an item to an IEnumerable than this

```
myNewIEnumerable = myIEnumerable.Concat ( Enumerable.Repeat (item, 1) );
```

?

Some context:

```
public void printStrings (IEnumerable<string> myStrings) {
   Console.WriteLine ("The beginning.");
   foreach (var s in myStrings) Console.WriteLine (s);
   Console.WriteLine ("The end.");
}

...

var result = someMethodDeliveringAnIEnumerableOfStrings ();
printStrings (result.Concat ( Enumerable.Repeat ("finished", 1) ) );
```

Comment: Probably not, IEnumerable is the wrong medium for this. Show more context for a better answer.

Comment: Poor context. You could just (and better) use an extra WriteLine() here.

Comment: @Henk, yup, the example is a little disappointing. I was expecting more injection of a data point into an existing query and less writing to the console.

Comment: Ok, I changed the example for you guys such that calling WriteLine outside printStrings does not work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way to append a single element to an `IEnumerable<T>` is to use this `AsIEnumerable` extension (although [Eric Lippert advises against](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7652359/284240) creating extension for objects):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsIEnumerable<T>(this T obj)
{
    yield return obj;
}  

var appended = source.Concat(element.AsIEnumerable())
```

or use this `Append<T>` extension: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3645715/284240

Comment: The AsEnumerable () is what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a remark: As I just noticed, it's important not to confuse AsIEnumerable with AsEnumerable ! It must be AsIEnumerable, of course.

Comment: @JohnB: Well, that is the core of this answer (and your question) since a single object is never an `IEnumerable` of it's type and has no `AsEnumerable()` method. We could rename it to `AsEnumerable` but that could cause misunderstandings  even more.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, there is. [Concat()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) takes any `IEnumerable<T>`, including arrays:

```
var myNewIEnumerable = myIEnumerable.Concat(new[] { item });
```

Comment: Hm, but this creates an array!? I'm not sure that's what I want.

Comment: @Henk, shouldn't the performance of `Concat()` be comparable to that of a custom iterator block that exhausts `myIEnumerable` then yields `item`?

Comment: @JohnB, yes, this creates an array of one element, the simplest enumerable construct I could think of.

Comment: Yeah, of course you are right, but I would really appreciate something like an AppendItem extension function.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - you're probably right, consuming the result should only iterate the original once.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own SingleConcat extension methods like so

```
public static class CustomConcat
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> SingleConcat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, T lastElement)
        {
            foreach (T t in first)
            {
                yield return t;
            }

            yield return lastElement;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> mylist = new List<int> { 1 , 2 , 3};

            var newList = mylist.SingleConcat(4);

            foreach (var s in newList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

This should print **1,2,3 followed by a 4**