# Send Method parameter as List without instantiating new List

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, parameter-passing, overloading

Lets say i have a method:

```
 UpdateObject(IList<MyObject> objs)
```

and i want to use that method for sending just one object? (i prefer not using method overloading cause i dont want a lot of methods to handle in my interface)

is there a way i could use the same method without doing the following:

```
UpdateObject(new List<MyObject>(){singleObj})
```

Comment: Chances are you'll be calling this method on the interface more often than you'll be implementing it.  The cost of adding an extra overload is probably cheaper than almost any change on the caller's side (when aggregated across all instances).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could pass an `IEnumerable<MyObject>` to that method instead.

Probably the easiest way to append a single element to an `IEnumerable<T>` is to use this `AsIEnumerable` extension (although [Eric Lippert advises against](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7652359/284240) creating extension for objects):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsIEnumerable<T>(this T obj)
{
    yield return obj;
}
```

Now you can use everything as `IEnumerable`.

```
UpdateObject(singleObj.AsIEnumerable())
```