# Extension Methods: Performance issue when using too much?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, extension-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extension Method Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006537/extension-method-performance)

Will I face performance issues when I´m using extension methods too heavy in any way?

Just an example:

Lets say I´ve 100 extension methods on the type string and a business object that has 50 string properties.
Now I create a collection of this business object, maybe 500 items?

Do these extension methods on string have any impact to RAM, CPU, ...?!

I really like extension methods but I´d like to know if there is a limitation concerning its usage.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No you will not.

Extension methods are just normal static methods with some syntactic sugar. Use them as much as you want :)

Comment: I'm writing an extension library so this is nice to know

Answer (score 5):

You might slow intellisense down in the IDE - and possibly make the intellisense lists a bit unwieldy, but it won't have any impact on the execution of the code itself over any other static method.

Answer (score 3):

An extension method is part of a static class, and it's a syntactic sugar because simulates that some static method is an instance method of some other class.

In conclusion, there's no performance penalty here. It's the same `ExtensionMethods.YourExtensionMethod(objectToAddMethod)` and `objectToAddMethod.YourExtensionMethod()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate:

See: [Is there a performance hit for creating Extension methods that operate off the object type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652118/is-there-a-performance-hit-for-creating-extension-methods-that-operate-off-the-o)

The answer there explains this very well!

Comment: If you think this is a duplicate, you need to comment out OP question instead of adding an useless answer ;)

Comment: how do i do that? I have just actively started to use StackOverflow so any tips would be nice.

Comment: @Digvijay Click `close` at the question. You need **[3000 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions)** though

Comment: @Digvijay I mean adding a comment to the question. sehe is right, but you can suggest anything with regular comments too.

Comment: @Matías I do not have enough privileges to comment anywhere yet!!! else i shall do so.

Comment: @Digvijay Oh, I didn't know that, I thought this was available for all.

Comment: The questions are similar but the context is at some extent different, I think they deserve their place as two separated questions